# Why does apache always redirect to the default VirtualHost?

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4, centos7, apache2

Im using apache 2.4 on centOS7.6 and I want to have one subdomain and the main domain, both showing different content. I have two VirtualHosts configured, both in different files in /etc/httpd/conf.d/

example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and subdomain.example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, no matter which domain i go to, i get the file from the default VirtualHost, which is the alphabetically first one. I tried changing the permissions of /var/www/ to 777, disabling selinux, switching the os to fedora30 and a few minor things.

main httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %v" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: You dis restart Apache httpd after creating those files? And depending on how the main Apache httpd.conf loads include snippets (look for the `Include` and `IncludeOptional` directives) your configuration snippets may need to have the .conf suffix

Comment: the file needs to end with `.conf`, otherwise apache wont load its content. so based on your example, the file should be called `subdomain.example.com.conf`

Comment: Yes i did restart Apache and it is called subdomain.example.com.conf i just forgot to add that in the post, as for the main httpd conf, ill add that to the post shortly

Comment: Just added it now

Comment: Do your logs show anything?